# Error : the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, Entity class given

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a `manyToMany` association between `Post` and `Category`. I am trying to submit the Post form to create a post with the selected category from the dropdown `<select>`.

Form is rendering correclty using:

```
<div id="form-categories-widget">
    <select id="shop_bundle_managementbundle_posttype_categories" 
        name="shop_bundle_managementbundle_posttype[categories]">
        {% for key,val in form.categories.vars.choices %}
        <option value="{{ val.value }}" {{  form.categories.vars.value == '' and key == 0 ? ' selected ' :(val.value == form.categories.vars.value ? ' selected ' : '') }}
            >
            {{ val.data.getName | trans }} 
        </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

**The problem:**

When I click on submit button I have the following error(for which I have spent about 2 days trying to figure out):

> The property "categories" in class
>   "Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Post" can be defined with the
>   methods "addCategory()", "removeCategory()" but the new value must be
>   an array or an instance of \Traversable,
>   "Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Category" given.

Here are my form type and entity (if ever they are useful). I thank you in advance for your invaluable time and help as usual.

**Entity Post:**

```
<?php

namespace Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity;

class Post
{
.....
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $categories;


    /**
     * Add category
     *
     * @param \Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Category $category
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addCategory(\Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories[$category->getName()] = $category;
        $category->addPost($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove category
     *
     * @param \Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Category $category
     */
    public function removeCategory(\Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($category);
    }

    /**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }


}
```

**PostType**

```
class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
                'multiple' => false,   // Multiple selection allowed
                'expanded' => false,   // Render as checkboxes
                'class' => 'ShopManagementBundle:Category',
                'property'     => 'name'
            ));

    }
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Post'

        ));
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'shop_bundle_managementbundle_posttype';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem were coming from the form template because I manually coded it forgetting double brackets `[]`. So instead of:

```
<select id="shop_bundle_managementbundle_posttype_categories" 
        name="shop_bundle_managementbundle_posttype[categories]">
```

I should have been using:

```
<select id="shop_bundle_managementbundle_posttype_categories" 
        name="shop_bundle_managementbundle_posttype[categories][]">
```

I hope other person don't make the same mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your field 'categories' need to be a CollectionType of entity and not just a entity.

In your example you try to replace $categories which is a collection by a Category entity.

Read this : [CollectionType Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

But I was of the opinion that there is a misunderstanding: You try to give multiple categories to a single post?
Have you reversed the thing? One Category contains multiple Posts ?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: As from my understanding, collection type is when you need to CREATE new instances of child entites, but when you have a predefined  set of child entities already created, using EntityType is more appropriate. when I dump `form.categories.vars` for both cases, the second case has a variable `choices` that contain my existing categories. About your question: yes I have the reversed side also (addPost, removePost, getPosts and initialization of $posts as arrayColletcion in constructor). Thank you for your time