# Symfony CollectionType self referencing

Tags: php, symfony

I have many to many association in my entity and i would like to use the collection type field from symfony to add multiple times.
I've never done this way before and i'm kinda lost.
The field  that i would like to have multiple times is headquarter with a non mapped field for each headquarter. 
The error that i'm getting;

> The property "headquarter" in class "AppBundle\Entity\SurveyManager"
>   can be defined with the methods "addHeadquarter()",
>   "removeHeadquarter()" but the new value must be an array or an
>   instance of \Traversable, "AppBundle\Entity\HeadQuarterManager" given.

The Form Type implementing the Collection.

```
class SurveyOptionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('headquarter', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => HeadQuarterType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => 'Sediu',
            ])
            ->add('isEnabled', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'Chestionar Activ',
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Salveaza',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SurveyManager::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is the Collection Form

```
class HeadQuarterType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('headquarter', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => HeadQuarterManager::class,
                'label' => 'Sediu',
            ])
            ->add('userNumber', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Numar Utilizatori',
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SurveyManager::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Here is the Entity class stripped away from all the uncesessary data

```
class SurveyManager
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\HeadQuarterManager")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="survey_headquarters",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="survey_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="headquarter_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $headquarter;

    public function __toString()
    {
        // TODO: Implement __toString() method.
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->question = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->headquarter = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }



    /**
     * Add headquarter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\HeadQuarterManager $headquarter
     *
     * @return SurveyManager
     */
    public function addHeadquarter(\AppBundle\Entity\HeadQuarterManager $headquarter)
    {
        $this->headquarter[] = $headquarter;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove headquarter
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\HeadQuarterManager $headquarter
     */
    public function removeHeadquarter(\AppBundle\Entity\HeadQuarterManager $headquarter)
    {
        $this->headquarter->removeElement($headquarter);
    }

    /**
     * Get headquarter
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getHeadquarter()
    {
        return $this->headquarter;
    }
}
```

Controller method

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$surveyRepository = $em->getRepository(SurveyManager::class);
//$surveyManager = $surveyRepository->findOneById($surveyId);
$surveyManager = new SurveyManager();
$form = $this->createForm(SurveyOptionType::class, $surveyManager);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($surveyManager);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_survey-manager_survey_options',
        [
            'id' => $surveyManager->getId()
        ]);
}

return [
    'surveyManager' => $surveyManager,
    'form' => $form->createView(),
];
```

While doing research about this i did a separate demo to test on it to see better the problem.

Here is an updated code simplified that should work really smooth

https://gist.github.com/bogdaniel/a0bcc848e2bd282382f45a2bd15cc0e2

You will find more info about the error in the gist.

Comment: It's not really clear what do you want to archive. Please provide definition of Headquarter, SurveyManager, Controller. And explain what does it mean - "The field that i would like to have multiple times is headquarter with a non mapped field for each headquarter.". The headquarter is not mapped to headquarter? There is no typo here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what do you want to archive, and what exactly does it mean:

> The field that i would like to have multiple times is headquarter with a non mapped field for each headquarter.

But the error is quite self-explaining. Your `SurveyManager` class has to have some methods to populate data from Form. The flow is following - Form gets data (from User, for example) with an array of headquarters. And then Form looks for the way to pass this array to the object - and doesn't find them because you don't have appropriate methods.

Id doesn't matter if the property is mapped (I believe, you mean mapped to Doctrine), it still has be provided a way to pass data from Form to Object.

Comment: if you look in the second form class i have a field with mapped => false, that was the field i was talking about that i want for each headquarter to have it. The data from the form is mapped to the entity. And i have the appropiate methods in the entity and it is weird because i shouldn't have had that error. i will update the question with the entity

Comment: i think the problem îs because i devine headquarter in the furat form as colection and tren in the colection form. And instead of getting the Array form collection it gets as an Object instance

Comment: No, the problem not about it. ArrayCollection works just fine. And it doesn't matter that you don't map some fields in HeadquarterType. In `SurveyOptionType` the `headquarter` option is mapped, and you don't have appropriate methods, that's it. Check your code twice, or just show it.

Comment: i've added in the main question the code from the controller

Comment: i've updated my question with a gist where you can see the same files but did in another project so i can modify and test faster. Also you will find there a full stack trace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124222/discussion-between-l-s-and-dmitry-malyshenko).

Answer (score 0):

How are you rendering your form? I suspect something similar to the issue found here: [Error : the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, Entity class given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270448/error-the-new-value-must-be-an-array-or-an-instance-of-traversable-entity-cl)

Other than that, the only issue I can see in your code is that the 'data_class' option from `HeadQuarterType` should be `HeadQuarterManager::class`.

Comment: well in normal way yeah the data class should be that one but i'm not writting data into that entity i only select data from that entity and add it to the many-to-many association

Comment: Doing a form collection would normally when you add data to the survey manager in my case embed a form to add data to another entity. but in my case i only want to add an association between headquarter manager and my survey :D